Outlet, breaker and wire size for a single circuit used by both a washer and a gas dryer
I'm buying a stacked washer/dryer (the old style top loader washer).  The dryer is gas and it will be replacing our old electric dryer.
There is an outlet in the laundry room with 12/2 wire and 20 amp breaker.  Can I use that single outlet to plug both the washer and GAS dryer into for use?  I've read some questions similar to this but it's never been clear that they can both be plugged into the same 20amp breaker.
The other option would be to wire up the old 10/3 wire and replace the 30 amp breaker with a regular 120 volt outlet and a 20 amp breaker (sans the red wire that I could cap off).
I could run another line 70 feet to the room but I have 2 outlets in there already - the current 120 volt, 12/2 wire with 20 amp breaker and the old 240 volt, 10/3 wire with a 30 amp breaker.  Thoughts?

What is the model #? The specs are what matters the most here.

TL;DR This will probably be OK.
Some stacked models actually have a way to connect the washer and dryer together - i.e., one plugs into the other, so there is only one cord going into the wall. Similar to the good old days when a PC would have a female connection for a power cord and a male connection for a special power cord to a monitor.
If that's the case, there should be overall specifications for the combined washer/dryer and if that is 120V and less than 20A, you're all set.
If that's not the case then you need to check the power requirements of the two units. Typical numbers in a quick search are 10A for a washer and 6A for a dryer. 16A is, conveniently, 80% of 20A, which makes it quite safe. Arguably you could go to 100% since these don't meet the usual definition of "continuous" loads (3 hours, I believe) and also are not hardwired.
If, for example, the washer has water heating capability (common for dishwashers, not so common for washing machines, at least in the US) or the dryer, despite being as, needs more power, then there could be an issue. But based on typical machines there should be no issue.

Thank you for the response.

The washer does not have a water heating capability.  It's a 3.8 CU FT tub with a typical gas dryer.  This is the old style stacked where the units are permanently connected and the washer is a top load.  My wife doesn't like front loading washers.

Model is:  GE - 3.8 Cu. Ft. Top Load Washer and 5.9 Cu. Ft. Gas Dryer Laundry Center - White.  Washer and dryer both listed at 120 volts.  Again, appreciate the comments and help.  Sorry for 3 posts.  Every time I hit enter to go to another line it submits my comment.

Found this on specs from GE: GUD27GSSM Gas Dryer – This appliance should be connected to an individual branch circuit with 120-volt single-phase 60 Hz electrical service and should be protected by 20-amp time-day fuses or circuit breakers. This appliance is equipped with a 4-foot long flexible U.S. listed 20-amp power cord to match a 20-amp receptacle.  Still not sure if both appliances can be plugged into the same 120 volt, 20 amp breaker outlet and used at the same time.

When I search for GUD27GSSM I get this combined washer/dryer A combined ("unitized") system by definition requires just what the specs there say, which on the web page is actually 15A or 20A. So if you are really talking about this combined unit then you're fine. If not, provide a link to the actual units (both washer and dryer).

That is the actual unit.  Thanks!  Really appreciate the help.
